# iOS Simulator display size configuration?

Tags: ios, simulator

Is there a setting or configuration option somewhere for the display size (iOS main window height and width in iOS points) that the iOS Simulator uses when launched to run an app? (other than the current default 480 and 1024 numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official, supported way to choose a screen size other than the four offered in the Hardware > Device menu (iPad, iPad retina, iPhone, iPhone retina).

[Cédric Luthi published a way](http://0xced.blogspot.com/2012/08/prepare-your-apps-for-new-iphone.html) to make the simulator use a retina screen size of 640x1136.  I don't know if his hack can be used to run at other resolutions.

Comment: This information became obsolete in mid-2014 when Apple introduced resizable devices in the iOS Simulator that came with Xcode 6.x.